# Laravel Argument 1 passed to HasOneOrMany::save() must be an instance of Model array given

Tags: php, laravel, model

I'm new at *Laravel* and I have a problem when I try to save array of data to database. Here's the error I get

> Argument 1 passed to
>   Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasOneOrMany::save() must be an
>   instance of Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model, array given, called in
>   S:\Documents\samdyk\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasOneOrMany.php
>   on line 267 and defined

So here's my code

```
class Skill extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['skill_title', 'knowledge_level'];
}

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    public function skills() {
        return $this->hasMany(Skill::class);
    }
}
```

And here's the controller function

```
public function editMyProfile(Request $request) {
        $user = Auth::user();

        dump($request->get('skills'));
       // dump($request->get('skills')[0]);
        dump($user->skills()->saveMany($request->get('skills')));
       return 1;
}
```

So here's `$request->get('skills')` data

```
array:5 [
  0 => array:2 [
    "skill_title" => "fghjghj"
    "knowledge_level" => "20"
  ]
  1 => array:2 [
    "skill_title" => "gjghjhgj"
    "knowledge_level" => "50"
  ]
  2 => array:2 [
    "skill_title" => "ghjhgjgfjh"
    "knowledge_level" => "80"
  ]
  3 => array:2 [
    "skill_title" => "hjkhgkkkhgjkjhkhjgk"
    "knowledge_level" => "53"
  ]
  4 => array:2 [
    "skill_title" => "jghjhgjhgj"
    "knowledge_level" => "57"
  ]
]
```

So as you can see I try to save an array (that's obvious). However even on laravel documentation I see this 
$post = App\Post::find(1);

```
$post->comments()->saveMany([
    new App\Comment(['message' => 'A new comment.']),
    new App\Comment(['message' => 'Another comment.']),
]);
```

So why my code is wrong?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need to pass an array of `Skill` objects to the `saveMany()` method:

```
$skillModels = [];
foreach ($request->skills as $skill) {
    $skillsModels[] = new Skill($skill);
}

$user->skills()->saveMany($skillModels);
```

And you're passing a simple array.

Comment: Thank You! I was struggling with this problem 3 hours! You saved me a lot of time. I will accept your answer as soon as I could. :)

Answer (score 7):

Just try createMany instead :)

```
$post->comments()->createMany([
    ['message' => 'A new comment.'],
    ['message' => 'Another comment.'],
]);
```

See the doc: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#the-create-method

Comment: This is the accurate salutation

Comment: The best solution.

Comment: Subtle solution